# How to code a 5-state toggle link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a HTML table where some TDs have inline styles, title tag and links
I would like that users could hide these elements **by pressing repeatedly the same icon** so that, for example, the first click removes styles only, the second click removes links only, the third click removes the title tags only, the fourth click removes everything and the fifth click restores all.

Here is how I manage to remove the single elements.

```
$('a .icon-remove').click(function () {
    $('.mindteq_content_tbl_container td[style]').css('background-color', '').css('color', '');
});
```

And the same for title tags and links

```
$('.tbl_container td a[title]').remove();

$('.tbl_container td a').removeAttr('href').css('border-bottom', '0px');
```

But I don't know how to make this kind of 5-state button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't remove the elements just use `hide()` because you'll need them later for showing again.

For a 5-state button you need an indicator to know what the links current state is. You can do this by using a variable or an aria-attribute.

**Sample using aria**

```
$(function() {
    $(".toggle").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var state = parseInt($this.attr('aria-state')) || 0;
        state++;

        $this.text("toggle "+state);
        switch(state) {
            case 5:
                //action 5
                break;
            case 4:
                //action 4
                break;
            case 3:
                //action 3
                break;
            case 2:
                //action 2
                break;
            case 1:
                //action 1
                break;
        }

        if(state >= 5)
            state = 0;

        $this.attr('aria-state', state);
    });    
});
```

[on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s01g2bn6/2/)

Further improvement would be to create a jquery-ui widget and create eventhandlers for the 5 states.

Comment: @Nicero Was working on it :-) Please check the updated answer.